# Jenkins pipeline clone and merge branches dynamically

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've used the Jenkins pipeline snippet generator to generate some code that clones a forked repository and merges branches from the original and forked project.

Here is the logic generated by the snippet generator:

```
checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: 'forkA/branchA']],
extensions: [cleanBeforeCheckout(),
            [$class: 'PreBuildMerge',
                options: [fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                mergeRemote: 'forkA',
                mergeTarget: 'branchB']],
            [$class: 'PreBuildMerge',
                options: [fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                mergeRemote: 'forkB',
                mergeTarget: 'branchC']],
            [$class: 'PreBuildMerge',
                options: [fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                mergeRemote: 'forkA',
                mergeTarget: 'branchA']],
            localBranch('branchA')],
userRemoteConfigs: [[name: 'forkA',
url: 'git@gitlab.blah.com:forkA/ProjectA'],
[name: 'forkB',
refspec: '+refs/heads/branchC:refs/remotes/forkB/branchC',
url: 'git@gitlab.gitlab.com:forkB/ProjectA']])
```

In my Jenkins Scripted pipeline, can I generate the **extensions** and **userRemoteConfigs** sections for the scmGit constructor dynamically?
I would like to generate it based on a list of maps (each map would have the fork and branch names).

These seem to be named parameters in the constructor, but I thought I might be able to generate an array of maps for each of the **PreBuildMerge** extensions and also for each **userRemoteConfig**, but I get an exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.extensions
> expects class hudson.plugins.git.extensions.GitSCMExtension but
> received class java.util.ArrayList    at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)

I can make this work dynamically by adding some methods in a global shared pipeline:

```
import hudson.plugins.git.extensions.GitSCMExtension
import hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.LocalBranch
import hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.CleanBeforeCheckout
import hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.PreBuildMerge
import hudson.plugins.git.UserMergeOptions
import hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig

def getExtensions(String branch, String repoName, Map repoBranchMap = [:]) {
    List<GitSCMExtension> extensions = []
    extensions.add(new CleanBeforeCheckout())

    repoBranchMap.each { repoBranchEntry ->
        String repo = repoBranchEntry.key
        List branchArray = repoBranchEntry.value

        branchArray.each { branchArrayEntry ->
            extensions.add(new PreBuildMerge(new UserMergeOptions(repo, branchArrayEntry, "default", org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.MergeCommand.GitPluginFastForwardMode.NO_FF)))
        }
    }

    extensions.add(new PreBuildMerge(new UserMergeOptions(repoName, branch, "default", org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.MergeCommand.GitPluginFastForwardMode.NO_FF)))
    extensions.add(new LocalBranch(branch))
    return extensions
}

def getUserRemoteConfigs(String gitRoot, String projectName, String repoName, Map repoBranchMap = [:]) {
    List<UserRemoteConfig> configs = []
    configs.add(new UserRemoteConfig("${gitRoot}${repoName}/${projectName}", repoName, "refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/${repoName}/*", null))

    repoBranchMap.each { repoBranchEntry ->
        String repo = repoBranchEntry.key
        List branchArray = repoBranchEntry.value
        String branchesRefspec = ''

        branchArray.each { branchArrayEntry ->
            branchesRefspec += "+refs/heads/${branchArrayEntry}:refs/remotes/${repo}/${branchArrayEntry} "
        }

        configs.add(new UserRemoteConfig("${gitRoot}${repo}/${projectName}", repo, branchesRefspec, null))
    }

    return configs
}

def gitSCM(String projectName, String branch, String repoName, Map repoBranchMap = [:], String directory = env.WORKSPACE) {
    dir(directory) {
        checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: "${repoName}/${branch}"]],
                extensions: getExtensions(branch, repoName, repoBranchMap),
                userRemoteConfigs: getUserRemoteConfigs(GIT_SSH_URL(), projectName, repoName, repoBranchMap))
    }
}
```

Which I call from my scripted pipeline with:

```
common.gitSCM('ProjectA', 'branchA', 'forkA', [forkA: ['branchB'], forkB: ['branchC'] ])
```

However you can see I need to import all the classes, and it's tightly coupled to the implementation classes.

If possible I'd like to be able to dynamically generate the **extensions** and **userRemoteConfigs**, but in a similar syntax that the snippet generator produced, just using what looks like arrays of maps etc.

Comment: What code did you try to use?

Comment: @NoamHelmer I've updated my question with some code that works. But it's not ideal, as I'm calling the constructors directly, which required me to pass all required parameters. Unlike how it's called by the code generated by the snippet generator. That's the syntax I'd like, but I need to generate it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I got some inspiration from the web page: [how-to-customize-checkout-for-pipeline-multibranch](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/how-to-customize-checkout-for-pipeline-multibranch)

I found I could dynamically generate the extensions and userRemoteConfigs by passing the **scm.extensions** and **scm.userRemoteConfigs** objects to methods updating them and then returning them.

So changing the logic generated by the snippet generator:

```
checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: "refs/remotes/${repoName}/${branch}"]],
        extensions: getExtensions(scm.extensions, branch, repoName, repoBranchMap),
        userRemoteConfigs: getUserRemoteConfigs(scm.userRemoteConfigs, GIT_SSH_URL(), projectName, repoName, repoBranchMap))
```

Then updating my **getExtensions()** and **getUserRemoteConfigs()** methods from my question above.

```
def getExtensions(def extensions, String branch, String repoName, Map repoBranchMap = [:]) {
    extensions = [cleanBeforeCheckout()]

    repoBranchMap.each { repoBranchEntry ->
        String repo = repoBranchEntry.key
        List branchArray = repoBranchEntry.value

        branchArray.each { branchArrayEntry ->
            extensions += [$class: 'PreBuildMerge',
                           options: [fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                                     mergeRemote: repo,
                                     mergeTarget: branchArrayEntry]]
        }
    }

    extensions += [$class: 'PreBuildMerge',
                   options: [fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                             mergeRemote: repoName,
                             mergeTarget: branch]]

    extensions += [localBranch(branch)]

    println("GitSCM Extensions: ${extensions}")
    return extensions
}

def getUserRemoteConfigs(def userRemoteConfigs, String gitRoot, String projectName, String repoName, Map repoBranchMap = [:]) {
    userRemoteConfigs = [[name: repoName,
                         url: "${gitRoot}${repoName}/${projectName}"]]

    repoBranchMap.each { repoBranchEntry ->
        String repo = repoBranchEntry.key

        if (repo != repoName) {  // only add remote for branches with different namespace
            List branchArray = repoBranchEntry.value
            String branchesRefspec = ''

            branchArray.each { branchArrayEntry ->
                if (branchesRefspec) {
                    branchesRefspec += ' '
                }
                branchesRefspec += "+refs/heads/${branchArrayEntry}:refs/remotes/${repo}/${branchArrayEntry}"
            }

            userRemoteConfigs += [[name   : repo,
                                   refspec: branchesRefspec,
                                   url    : "${gitRoot}${repo}/${projectName}"]]
        }
    }

    println("GitSCM User Remote Configs: ${userRemoteConfigs}")
    return userRemoteConfigs
}
```

So these new methods are more flexible in that I don't need to import any **impl** packages (as in my more Java solution in the question above). You can see I'm appending `+=` to the **scm.extensions** and **scm.userRemoteConfigs** objects, to add **PreBuildMerge** of the appropriate branches, and their remote configurations.

Happy for any better suggestions though.